# TYPO3 Powermail 2.x: Delete upload files from server after the mail was sent.

Tags: typo3, powermail

In Powermail 1.x i could set this feature in the Powermail Constants:

```
# cat=powermail uploads/enable/0530; type=boolean; label= Delete after attach: If checked, all uploaded files will be deleted from the server after the mail was sent
    upload.delete = 0
```

Is it not possible anymore to delete the uploaded files from the server? Is the only way to delete these files with a cronjob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a own cronjob.

Go to the scheduler, add a new task, choose "Extbase Command Controller Task".

Open the "CommandController Command" drop down. There you will find the task "powermail: Clean Unused Uploads".

Comment: I had an old Powermail 2.0.20 Version. In this version the are no Scheduler tasks. An update to the new Powermailversion did solve the problem.